# google analytics event tracking from multiple websites

Tags: events, google-analytics, event-tracking

I have two websites with two unique URLs, each with GA installed.
The basics of my issue is ... website A is seeing the Event Tracking for website B
Website B has been set up for some years and the GA functioned correctly, however, earlier this year the original URL was assigned to website A and website B was assigned a new URL. I have the appropriate GA code installed for each URL

Website B GA Code =

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-20989255-32', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Website A GA Code =

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-20989255-16', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Event tracking is enabled on both websites and Website B Event tracking appears to function correctly, however Website A Event tracking contains events from both website A and B.
The event(s) in question I am tracking are File Downloads (PDF)
Both websites have Event Tracking enabled and the code for each website is identical with the exception of the GA account number

```
     <script type="text/plain" class="cc-onconsent-analytics">

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-20989255-16']); /* used for website A 
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-20989255-32']); /* used for website B 
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();

      </script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var filetypes = /\.(zip|exe|dmg|pdf|doc.*|xls.*|ppt.*|mp3|txt|rar|wma|mov|avi|wmv|flv|wav)$/i;
    var baseHref = '';
    if (jQuery('base').attr('href') != undefined) baseHref = jQuery('base').attr('href');

    jQuery('a').on('click', function(event) {
      var el = jQuery(this);
      var track = true;
      var href = (typeof(el.attr('href')) != 'undefined' ) ? el.attr('href') :"";
      var isThisDomain = href.match(document.domain.split('.').reverse()[1] + '.' + document.domain.split('.').reverse()[0]);

      if (!href.match(/^javascript:/i)) {
        var elEv = []; elEv.value=0, elEv.non_i=false;
        if (href.match(/^mailto\:/i)) {
          elEv.category = "email";
          elEv.action = "click";
          elEv.label = href.replace(/^mailto\:/i, '');
          elEv.loc = href;
        }
        else if (href.match(filetypes)) {
          var extension = (/[.]/.exec(href)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(href) : undefined;
          elEv.category = "download";
          elEv.action = "click-" + extension[0];
          elEv.label = href.replace(/ /g,"-");
          elEv.loc = baseHref + href;
        }
        else if (href.match(/^https?\:/i) && !isThisDomain) {
          elEv.category = "external";
          elEv.action = "click";
          elEv.label = href.replace(/^https?\:\/\//i, '');
          elEv.non_i = true;
          elEv.loc = href;
        }
        else if (href.match(/^tel\:/i)) {
          elEv.category = "telephone";
          elEv.action = "click";
          elEv.label = href.replace(/^tel\:/i, '');
          elEv.loc = href;
        }
        else track = false;

        if (track) {
          _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', elEv.category.toLowerCase(), elEv.action.toLowerCase(), elEv.label.toLowerCase(), elEv.value, elEv.non_i]);
          if ( el.attr('target') == undefined || el.attr('target').toLowerCase() != '_blank') {
            setTimeout(function() { location.href = elEv.loc; }, 400);
            return false;
      }
    }
      }
    });
  });
}
</script>
```

Has anybody come across a similar issue ... I suspect the event Tracking is still listening for the original URL in some way ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be straightforward - the website will only track into whichever property is on the page, UNLESS you have other code elsewhere that is interfering and does otherwise. I think in your case, your mixing and mingling of classic GA code and UA may have something to do with it.

You are sending your events with the older GA syntax:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', elEv.category.toLowerCase(), elEv.action.toLowerCase(), elEv.label.toLowerCase(), elEv.value, elEv.non_i]);
```

but you should completely remove all that older stuff, including the `ga.js` code snippet, and replace it with the new syntax:

```
ga('send', 'event', elEv.category.toLowerCase(), elEv.action.toLowerCase(), elEv.label.toLowerCase(), elEv.value, elEv.non_i);
```

Comment: Hi Nyuen and many thanks for your input. I hadn't realised my GA code was such a mix-up. The first thing I will do is update to the latest code and then see what the result is.